# Parity Peers Display

Tags: parity, nodes

Using Parity, sometimes I see something like:

```
2017-09-25 00:19:21     1/25 peers
```

and sometimes it's

```
2017-09-24 16:19:13     0/ 2/25 peers
```

What is that first number?

Why does it only appear sometimes?

Why does it mean that it's zero?

Thank you.

Comment: The one showing you three numbers is outdated by at least 3 months, please upgrade :)

Comment: @5chdn Okay thank you.  Also which question is the duplicate?  Is it possible to include that when marking a duplicate?  Sometimes because of the SE interface I do not realize that my question was accepted.  I get a blank page and have to retype it.  But now I can't find my other question to actually get an answer.

Comment: @5chdn I checked and the version with three number is Parity/v1.7.0-unstable from July 28.  So only two months old.  I will upgrade to 1.7.2 but also want to make sure you know I was not running some ancient version.  Is it really important to upgrade every two months to a minor -.-.2 version?

Comment: No, if you run a stable or beta version, you are fine for a couple of weeks, but if you run a nightly version, you should upgrade daily.

Comment: @5chdn if you make your first comment (re: upgrade) into an answer, I will mark it complete.  But it would be nice to know what the legacy answer was regarding that first number.